# JQuery toggle button changes text

Tags: jquery, if-statement, toggle, visibility

I'm playing around with JQuery and trying to make a simple program.  Basically, I want to a button that toggles the visibility of a paragraph, and I want the text on the button to change with the visibility of "p".  The first part works, the second part doesn't.

I know there are other questions asking about this sort of thing, but I've tried to mimmic so many different things and can't get the results, so I figured I'd just ask.  Here's the code I have right now.

```
<script>  $(document).ready(function(){

        $("button").click(function(){

   $("p").toggle();

        });
    });

if (p.style.visibility==="hidden")
   {
       $("button").text("show text");
   }
   else
   {
       $("button").text("hide text");
   }

    </script>
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: Have you tried `$("p").css("visibility") === "hidden"` for the if-statement? Right now you're accessing the variable `p`, which is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Don't check if the visibility has changed, check if the display has. `.toggle()` doesn't change the visibility.

```
if (p.style.display==="none")
   {
       $("button").text("show text");
   }
   else
   {
       $("button").text("hide text");
   }
```

There are better ways to do this, but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, put your code inside onclick function:

```
 $("button").click(function(){
   $("p").toggle();
   // change your text here
});
```

Second, p is not declared anywhere. Select it with $('p'). Instead of checking its visibility you can toggleClass 'active' and check if p has class active or not.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").toggle();

        // Check it inside here and select p correctly
        if( $("p").is(":visible")){
          $("button").text("hide text");
        } else {
          $("button").text("show text");
        }
      });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Hide text</button>
<p>Hi, this is text!</p>
```